# Getting image url from globals asset field

Tags: assets, craft3, globals

I can retrieve only the image title from the below code, I can't see why the image URL is showing as empty? its a global handle 'brand' and asset field 'logo':

```
{% set image = brand.logo.one %}

<a href="/">
    <img class="logo" src="{{ image.getUrl() }} alt="{{ image.title }}">
</a>
```

Comment: Does your volume has public urls? That's mostly the issue when someone asks this question

Comment: Did you try to add the relative path https://www.domain.com/globalassets/imagename.svg

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Andrew Fairlie for pointing out I need to make sure Assets in this volume have public URLs set